# Scrolling in a CListCtrl , after update poses issues

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm using a `CListCtrl` and under certain conditions, I need to update the contents of the `CListCtrl`

However, after an update happens, scrolling the `CListCtrl`, becomes an issue. The UI completely gets corrupted by showing the same row, multiple times etc.,

I'm updating the listcontrol using `SetItemText()`.  Have you encountered the same before and how do I resolve it?

Note: I tried overriding `OnVScroll` and calling the base class's `VScroll`. That doesn't seem to help either.

After the update, I also, refreshed the list control, using

```
CListCtrl::RedrawWindow(NULL,NULL,RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ERASE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
```

Comment: Are you certain that the UI is malfunctioning by displaying the same row multiple times, and that you have not inserted or copied that row multiple times? A screenshot may be a good idea here.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure, I'm not inserting. This problem happens, only when I update a column.

Comment: Are you turning off redraw anywhere with a SetRedraw?

Comment: Are you updating multiple items? Why do you need to force redraw? It should not be necessary. Could you please posr a code snippet showing how you use SetItemText?

Comment: m_lstList->SetItemText( iRowToChangeA, iColToChange ,str);
m_lstList->SetRedraw(TRUE);
m_lstList->RedrawWindow(NULL,NULL,RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ERASE | RDW_UPDATENOW);

Comment: As JohnCz said, you shouldn't need to force a redraw. SetItemText() will invalidate the appropriate areas for you. Why are you doing this?